# xdebug.var_display_max_data doesn't work

Tags: php, xdebug

I am working on a PHP project and I want to test a string that is quite long. And I set a watch to monitor this string. However when the length of this string hits some limitation, the value of it shows "Evaluation...".

The following is my conf

```
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
```

It seems that `xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1` doesn't work.

This problem occurs when I use substr() function. For example, `substr($string, 0, 2048)` works, but `substr($string, 0, 2049)` shows 'null'.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but it works for me. Are you sure your config is being read correctly? What does `phpinfo()` say your `var_display_max_data` is set to?

Comment: phpinfo() shows the var_display_max_data is -1.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `$string`?